# List/Itemize with image bullets

Tags: spacing, graphics, formatting

I want to have something like bullets but with images, I found an example but it doesn't align quite well. The text should be aligned to the center of the image and the image (preferably it's center) should be align to the other paragraphs.

This is a contrast of the wrong and the right result:
[image]

[Example code](https://www.overleaf.com/read/szpkvcfpmgqj), this is just an implementation feel free to do it your way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

    \newcommand*{\warn}{%
     \item[{\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{Trees5}}]%
    }

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}



\begin{document}
Once upon a time, there was a little girl who lived in a village near the forest.  Whenever she went out, the little girl wore a red riding cloak, so everyone in the village called her Little Red Riding Hood.

One morning, Little Red Riding Hood asked her mother if she could go to visit her grandmother as it had been awhile since they'd seen each other.
\begin{itemize}
  \warn Granny is saved.
  \warn The wolf dies.
  \warn Hello world.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) trough a dedicated `gitemize` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlist{gitemize}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[gitemize,1]{
  leftmargin=\dimexpr0.3cm+\labelsep\relax,
  label={\smash{\raisebox{-0.25\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{example-image-a}}}}
}

\begin{document}
Once upon a time, there was a little girl who lived in a village near the forest.  Whenever she went out, the little girl wore a red riding cloak, so everyone in the village called her Little Red Riding Hood.

One morning, Little Red Riding Hood asked her mother if she could go to visit her grandmother as it had been awhile since they'd seen each other.
\begin{gitemize}
  \item Granny is saved. Little Red Riding Hood asked her mother if she could go to visit her grandmother as it had been awhile since they'd seen each other.
  \item The wolf dies.
  \item Hello world.
\end{gitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All alignment parameters are easily adjustable. I added the `showframe` package just to have a visual guide of the text area.

Comment: If I don't add newlist and setlist after \begin{document} it won't compile (I get errors)

Comment: Also, what does the {4} setting  do after {itemize}?

Comment: @user2692669 That error indicates that your version of enumitem is outdated. Please update it. The 4 indicates that the new list will have four possible nesting levels, just in case one needs them. You can change it to 1 if no more than one nedting level is required.

Comment: It's fresh (texlive 2015 - enunmitem version: 24146 (3.5.2) )

Comment: @user2692669 Then there should be no errors. Is the error appearing with the exact code I posted (I mean, not a copy-paste to an already existing document, but just the exact code in my answer)?

Comment: The standalone compiles, I guess it must be the template (for the 100th time :P ). (It also compiles inside the document with the way I told before, it's acceptable by me but I'm worried if I add anything else the template will "explode" :P)

Comment: @user2692669 I see. As you say, the problem is then elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This is roughly what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\newcommand{\parimage}{%
  \par\noindent
  \smash{%
    \makebox[0pt]{%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.3\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[height=7pt]{example-image-1x1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \hspace*{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

Once upon a time, there was a little girl who lived in a village near the forest. 
Whenever she went out, the little girl wore a red riding cloak, so everyone in the 
village called her Little Red Riding Hood.

One morning, Little Red Riding Hood asked her mother if she could go to visit her 
grandmother as it had been awhile since they'd seen each other.

\parimage Granny is saved.

\parimage The wolf dies.

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The alignment of the image and the paragraph text can be adjusted.

Comment: Is there a way to indent all the paragraph like the first line so text doesn't get under the image? Great answer by the way.

Comment: @user2692669: Try [this paste](http://pastebin.com/W2YLEzEw). It removes any `\parindent` and sets the image in the left margin. Not sure whether that's what you're after.