# How to align the icon in an itemize environment?

Tags: alignment, svg, icon

I'd like to align the icon with the text. I prefer to put the icon outside the text instead of changing the line height.

The svg file https://svgur.com/s/vr6

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{svg}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    \begin{itemize}[label={\includesvg{text editor_icon.svg}}]
    \item \textit{Real-time Environment}: 

To encourage the collaborative aspect of prototyping activity we 
designed a real-time workflow, where the collaborators individually 
yet simultaneously participate in the story design. 
All different panels and features in DataStoryDesign are in 
real-time. Real-time systems remove the burden regarding physical 
distance requirements for certain activities. 
However, we don't evaluate this aspect since the focus of 
this study is on the applicability of the design language. 
Therefore we are more interested in knowing the effect of 
the design language on the prototyping and storyboarding process.

    \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Give MWE please! Since there is an `\item` at the beginning, you might use some list-type environment which we can't get to know what the env is if you don't show the complete code.

Comment: check my update plz

Comment: what is MWE ?

this is a template I'm using, it's for university, how can I give you the full code ?

Comment: is this what you mean ?

Comment: MWE is [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: We need code we can copy and test on our side. The code should note depend on files we don not have. So I'd replace the SVN by say `\rule{8mm}{8mm}` as the specifix gfx is not related to the question.

Comment: okay, I put the full code

Comment: Just for my curiosity: did you try to compile the code you post(ed) ? Is is yours, or "created" by ChatGPT or similar?

Comment: thank you.......

Comment: Can you describe more what the desired output should be? It would help if you can annotate the screenshot to show what's wrong with it as it stands and what needs to be improved. Right now I don't quite understand what you are looking for.

Comment: no I compiled it here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_latex_editor.php

Comment: I want to bring down the svg image to be aligned with the first line of the text

Comment: I'm very noob in latex

Comment: Your MWE lacks a `\begin{document}` and the `enuitem` package. Please test before posting a question.

Comment: I have many packages, I got confused sorry

Comment: @KamranAsgari That's why you always have to test your examples before asking a question.

Comment: Similar question (with `\smash` and `\raisebox`): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273030/list-itemize-with-image-bullets

Comment: side note: if using this "label" a lot, for performance it would probably be better to store the included svg in a box and use this one in repetition as the graphic inclusion is done only once

Comment: Thanks Stephan, fixed it with that solution

Comment: Why do you keep using \showframe package ? it mess the whole document with a black frame

Comment: Are you trying to align something as an interior column note, or are you trying to wrap the text into the figure (if the latter, see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) for `wrapfig`)?

Comment: @KamranAsgari The `showframe` package is not for your real document. Some people use it in their answers to visualize how their result fits on the page.

Comment: I posted it, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\newlist{realTime}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[realTime,1]{
  leftmargin=\dimexpr0.3cm+\labelsep\relax,
  label={\smash{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{{\includesvg{text editor_icon.svg}}}}}}


\begin{realTime}
  \item \textit{Real-time Environment}: To encourage the collaborative aspect of prototyping and storyboarding activity we designed a real-time workflow, where the collaborators individually yet simultaneously participate in the story design. All different panels and features in DataStoryDesign are in real-time. Real-time systems remove the burden regarding physical distance requirements for certain activities. However, we don't evaluate this aspect since the focus of this study is on the applicability of the design language. Therefore we are more interested in knowing the effect of the design language on the prototyping and storyboarding process.
\end{realTime}

\end{document}
```